# how to select datatable where datatable i got from excel?

Tags: c#, console-application

i have problem on C# console application.
i declare :

> DataTable MasterExcel = *this read frem excel*

and i already check MasterExcel have 141 data.
but when  i try to select :

> DataRow[] result = MasterExcel.select("Name= 'Adam'");

there should be one data found. but "result" still cant find any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I try to check again in my code:

```
DataTable MasterExcel = this read from excel
```

I did realize that the return column header name isn't "Name" but is "Column4".
and that day I change it, and now its working with both code:

```
MasterExcel.Select("Name= 'Adam'");
```

or

```
MasterExcel.Select("Name Like '*Adam*'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
MasterExcel.Select("Name like '*Adam*'");
```

If also this don't work, problem related with excel data

Comment: sorry for late reply, thanks for your help, i try to check again in my code:
DataTable MasterExcel = this read frem excel
and i did realize that the return column header name isn't "Name" but its "Column4".
and that day i change it, and now its work with both code:
DataRow[] result = MasterExcel.select("Name= 'Adam'");
or
DataRow[] result = MasterExcel.select("Name= 'Adam'");


Thanks & Regard.
Silver Crows :)